# How to convert legacy iterators to the new C++20 iterators? Can I mix them together?

Tags: c++, iterator, range, c++20, c++-concepts

C++20 introduces new iterator concepts, different from the requirements of the old legacy iterators. Therefore, from my understanding, the legacy iterators are not interchangeable with the new C++20 iterators. However, sometimes dealing with legacy iterators is still needed, e.g. `map::find` returns a [`LegacyBidirectionalIterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator), whose requirements are not exactly the same as a [`bidirectional_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/bidirectional_iterator). What should I do if I need the new `bidirectional_iterator`, in order to be used with the new C++20 ranges library? Can I somehow convert the `LegacyBidirectionalIterator` to a `bidirectional_iterator`? My guess would be that, in practice, in most cases, the legacy iterator can be used as is, however this doesn't seem to be guaranteed by the standard.

**[EDIT]**

Even if a legacy iterator is compatible with the C++20 iterator, that still doesn't mean they can be mixed, e.g. that the following is legitimate:

```
std::map<int, int> myMap;
...
if( myMap.find(6) == std::ranges::end(myMap) )
    ...
```

While in this case I could simply use the old `std::end` instead of `std::ranges::end`, in other situations I could be obliged to deal with both legacy iterators and C++20 iterators together.

Comment: From a quick scan `LegacyBidirectionalIterator` compiles with `bidirectional_iterator` but not the other way round. Therefore passing a `LegacyBidirectionalIterator` to something that requires `bidirectional_iterator` should work

Comment: The new concepts exist to support the new range based library algorithms. So allow me a frame challange: do you believe the new algorithms would ever get added, if they *intentionally* couldn't work with the containers library? Such a proposal would be dead upon arrival.

Comment: For the C++20 iterators system, just use those concepts, and if `LegacyIterator` satisfies the constraints (in most cases) then there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: The iterator requirements, especially of the new iterators, seem to be complex and delicate. It's hard to be sure I'm not missing something. @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Makes sense, but mistakes do happen, especially with such a complicated library, and maybe they have other considerations why the old iterators (whose definition can't be changed because people rely on thems) can't always be fully compatible with the new ones. I just wish that `cppreference` and the C++ Standard referred to such compatibility issues (maybe they do but I'm not currently aware to any mention of those issues).

Comment: Another issue: What if I need to mix legacy iterators with C++20 iterators? Even if the legacy iterators are fully compatible with the C++20 iterators, that doesn't mean they can be mixed, e.g. that you can compare a legacy iterator and a C++20 iterator. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "compare them"? `Legacy*Iterator`s are named requirements; they are not types. If you have a type `It`, it can satisfy `LegacyWeIterator` and/or `std::we_iterator`, but it's still just one type and two such objects of type `It` may be compared.

Comment: I believe you are right, it seems like `std::ranges::begin` is a generalization of `std::begin`, and when the later is valid, they both return the same. Still would be nice if it was stated explicitly somewhere

Comment: @YaronCohen-Tal That is definitely not true. It is very easy to construct situations where `std::begin(c)` is valid but `std::ranges::begin(c)` is not, since `std::begin(c)` just means `c.begin()`, whatever that expression does.

Comment: According to [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/begin), that's also what `std::ranges::begin` does. Can you give an example where my assertion is false?

Comment: @YaronCohen-Tal No, that's not what it says. [Here's a simple example](https://godbolt.org/z/Ech6T5zGc)

Comment: That proves nothing. The legacy iterators are obliged to satisfy a set of [requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Iterator), however those are only part of the standard; they're not obliged to comply to a C++20 concept, because they were introduced long before C++20. The C++20 iterators, however, must comply to actual C++20 concepts, which would issue a compiler error immediately in case they're not satisfied. In your example, the return value of `C::begin` (which is `void`) obviously doesn't satisfy the requirements of a `LegacyIterator`, e.g. it's not even dereferenceable.